# Sort Nested Data Structure

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a nested hash (see below) I would like to sort siblings which have a ':position' attribute.

In the hash below you can see the child and child_child attributes being an array but the position isn't ordered.

```
{:parent=>
      [{:id=>"29637484-4d39-4828-bebc-52e4ecb12250",
        :extra_data=>"parent_extra_data_1two",
        :position=>2,
        :resource_id=>"parent_resource_id_1two",
        :child=>
         [{:id=>"57c9dab3-f091-48e7-85a7-4a8a3c4782a6", :extra_data=>"child_extra_data_1two", :position=>2, :resource_id=>"child_resource_id_2two"},
          {:id=>"86b60506-f431-41f4-8555-30a83e9296f9",
           :extra_data=>"child_extra_data_1",
           :position=>1,
           :resource_id=>"child_resource_id_1",
           :child_child=>
            [{:id=>"04bb9af2-eac8-4fcf-8253-38b0ccb538c2", :extra_data=>"child_child_extra_data_one", :position=>1, :resource_id=>"child_child_one"},
             {:id=>"94947cc4-e27a-4f79-b585-f26db7ce4e66", :extra_data=>"child_child_extra_data_three", :position=>3, :resource_id=>"child_child_three"},
             {:id=>"98fe0b96-a8cd-488b-bf00-9d48633355d3", :extra_data=>"child_child_extra_data_two", :position=>2, :resource_id=>"child_child_two"}]}]}]}
```

Would become

```
{:parent=>
      [{:id=>"29637484-4d39-4828-bebc-52e4ecb12250",
        :extra_data=>"parent_extra_data_1two",
        :position=>2,
        :resource_id=>"parent_resource_id_1two",
        :child=>
         [{:id=>"86b60506-f431-41f4-8555-30a83e9296f9",
           :extra_data=>"child_extra_data_1",
           :position=>1,
           :resource_id=>"child_resource_id_1",
           :child_child=>
              [{:id=>"04bb9af2-eac8-4fcf-8253-38b0ccb538c2", :extra_data=>"child_child_extra_data_one", :position=>1, :resource_id=>"child_child_one"},
              {:id=>"98fe0b96-a8cd-488b-bf00-9d48633355d3", :extra_data=>"child_child_extra_data_two", :position=>2, :resource_id=>"child_child_two"},
              {:id=>"94947cc4-e27a-4f79-b585-f26db7ce4e66", :extra_data=>"child_child_extra_data_three", :position=>3, :resource_id=>"child_child_three"}]},
          {:id=>"57c9dab3-f091-48e7-85a7-4a8a3c4782a6", 
          :extra_data=>"child_extra_data_1two", 
          :position=>2, 
          :resource_id=>"child_resource_id_2two"
          }]}]}
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ddubs thanks again for the recursion idea. Quite challenging as I've never had to use recursion before.

```
def sort_tree(tree)
    tree.each_key.map { |atr|
        if obj_keys.include? atr #obj_keys is an array of symbols [:parent, child, child_child]
            tree[atr].sort_by!{|q| q[:position]}
            tree[atr].map! {|q| sort_tree(q)}
        end
        {atr => tree[atr]}
    }.reduce(:merge)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun exercise in recursive functions, you really should try to work these things out though as they will certainly improve your skills.

```
def sort_me(data)
  if data.is_a? Array
    data.sort_by! { |h| h[:position] }
    data.map { |i| sort_me(i) }
  elsif data.has_key? :child
    if data[:child].is_a? Array
      data[:child].map { |i| sort_me(i) }
    end
    return data[:child].sort_by! { |h| h[:position] }
  elsif data.has_key? :child_child
    return data[:child_child].sort_by! { |h| h[:position] }
  end
  return data
end

puts sort_me(data[:parent]).to_yaml
```

YAML results (easier for the eyes)

```
---
- :id: 29637484-4d39-4828-bebc-52e4ecb12250
  :extra_data: parent_extra_data_1two
  :position: 2
  :resource_id: parent_resource_id_1two
  :child:
  - :id: 86b60506-f431-41f4-8555-30a83e9296f9
    :extra_data: child_extra_data_1
    :position: 1
    :resource_id: child_resource_id_1
    :child_child:
    - :id: 04bb9af2-eac8-4fcf-8253-38b0ccb538c2
      :extra_data: child_child_extra_data_one
      :position: 1
      :resource_id: child_child_one
    - :id: 98fe0b96-a8cd-488b-bf00-9d48633355d3
      :extra_data: child_child_extra_data_two
      :position: 2
      :resource_id: child_child_two
    - :id: 94947cc4-e27a-4f79-b585-f26db7ce4e66
      :extra_data: child_child_extra_data_three
      :position: 3
      :resource_id: child_child_three
  - :id: 57c9dab3-f091-48e7-85a7-4a8a3c4782a6
    :extra_data: child_extra_data_1two
    :position: 2
    :resource_id: child_resource_id_2two
```

Comment: Thanks for the recursive function hint. I'll take your advice and try doing this myself before reading your full answer.